# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor

Tags: java, bytecode, classnotfoundexception

here is my question:
I have a maven project and already have it packaged,it provides some api on modifying java bytecode(using asm).
However,when I added it to another gradle project's dependency,it went wrong.
it says:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor
> PluginClassLoader(plugin=PluginDescriptor(name=Jacoconut,
> id=org.njuse.testPlugin, descriptorPath=plugin.xml,
> path=~\Desktop\testPlugin\build\idea-sandbox\plugins\testPlugin,
> version=1.0-SNAPSHOT, package=null), packagePrefix=null,
> instanceId=61, state=active)

The target gradle project intends to develop a intellij plugin, concerning code coverage.
build.gradle looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.intellij' version '1.3.0'
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.njuse'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'com.github.javaparser', name: 'javaparser-core', version: '3.23.1'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.maven.shared', name:'maven-verifier',version: '1.6'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2'

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'lib',includes: ['*.jar'])
}

// See https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin/
intellij {
    version = '2021.2.2'
    plugins=['java']

}
patchPluginXml {
    changeNotes = """
      Add change notes here.<br>
      <em>most HTML tags may be used</em>"""
}
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile){
    options.encoding="UTF-8"
}

jar {
    enabled = true
}
```

and pom.xml looks like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoconut</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <asm.version>9.2</asm.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <bootclasspath>${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/rt.jar</bootclasspath>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ow2.asm/asm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>${asm.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ow2.asm/asm-commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-commons</artifactId>
            <version>${asm.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ow2.asm/asm-util -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-util</artifactId>
            <version>${asm.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ow2.asm/asm-tree -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-tree</artifactId>
            <version>${asm.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ow2.asm/asm-analysis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-analysis</artifactId>
            <version>${asm.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```